# Problema con num_rows

Tags: php, poo

Buenas tardes,

Tengo este código que se supone que me tiene que dar el número de libros que hay en la base de datos, pero no funciona.

```
public function getTotalBooks() {

            $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM libros");
            $result = $sql->execute();
            $rows = $result->num_rows();

            echo $rows;

        }
```

Me da este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\CBSLibrary\assets\private\classes\class.statics.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\CBSLibrary\administration\settings\library.php(265): Statics->getTotalBooks() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\CBSLibrary\assets\private\classes\class.statics.php on line 17
```

He probado a hacerlo de mil maneras después de 1 hora buscando en internet el error, pero no he encontrado ninguna que funcione.

Comment: ¿Estas usando `MySQLi` o `PDO`?

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Estoy usando PDO que yo sepa, como soy nuevo capaz que se me ha colado algo de mysqli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenemos que:

- [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) devuelve un [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdostatement.php), por lo que la variable `$sql` es un objeto de este tipo.
- [`PDOStatement::execute`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php), devuelve `bool`, por lo que la variable `$result` es un booleano, es decir no es un objeto, es por esta razón que recibes el error.

### Solución:

Una forma de hacerlo sería así:

- Si la DB posee la función `COUNT()`

  ```
  public function getTotalBooks() {

      $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM libros");
      $sql->execute();
      $rows = $sql->fetchColumn();
      echo $rows;
  }
  ```
- Si la DB **no** posee la función `COUNT()`

  ```
  public function getTotalBooks() {

      $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM libros");
      $sql->execute();
      $results = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      echo count($results);
  }
  ```

Comment: He probado las dos opciones, pero la primera no devuelve nada y la segunda devuelve 0. (Hay 2 libros en la bd) Y el tema de la conexión a la db funciona ya que otras funciones no tienen ningún problema. La verdad es que no entiendo nada, he probado muchas formas y ninguna funciona. @MarcosGallardo (ninguna de las dos opciones me lanza ningun error)

Comment: @CharlieClewer, he actualizado mi respuesta. Olvide llamar a `execute` después del `prepare`. Vale la pena mencionar que la opción usando `COUNT` es la óptima.

Comment: funciona perfectamente ahora, muchas gracias :)

Comment: buena respuesta, como tips : estas en una funcion y no devuelves nada deberias de devolver el resultado

Comment: Buena respuesta, ya que rowCount no es la mejor opción para contar registros. Falta dotar a la función de un `return` y optimizar la segunda opción, ya que seleccionar todos `*` para contar ... mejor: `SELECT id_libro FROM libros;` algunas usan también `SELECT 1 FROM tabla` aunque como se ha dicho `COUNT(*)` podría ser la opción más óptima,